# Pandas append sheet to workbook if sheet doesn't exist, else overwrite sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am updating an existing Excel workbook using pandas. When using an `ExcelWriter` object, can I overwrite a sheet if it exists and otherwise create a new sheet? The code I have appends new sheets, but when I try to overwrite an existing sheet it appends a new sheet with a slightly varied name (ex: If sheet 'data1' exists, running the code appends a new sheet named 'data1 1').

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
path = 'test-out.xlsx'
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(10)})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a')
writer.book = book
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: have you tried checking whether sheet exists? And deleting it (or clearing its contents) before `to_excel`?

Comment: I think I will have to do this to take care of overwriting existing sheets. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the sheets to the `writer` with `writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
path = 'test-out.xlsx'
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(10)})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data1')
writer.save()
```

**Edit:**

Seems like you don't even need `mode='w'`, `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a')` is still working...

Comment: fyi, pd.ExcelWriter(exl[i], engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") does the same for the task. but for some reason it works in windows env and not linux (i checked file permissions was not the reason). in linux it created new sheets instead of overwriting existing one. But the accepted answer works fine in both windows and linux.