# Pandas: if_sheet_exists "replace" not working

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code:

```
def save_excel_sheet(df, filepath, sheetname, index=False):
    # Create file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        df.to_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheetname, index=index)

    # Otherwise, add a sheet. Overwrite if there exists one with the same name.
    else:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace', mode='a') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=index)
```

The expected behavior would be that when call the function on an existing file, with an existing sheet of name "sheetname", it should replace/overwrite the sheet.
But it doesn't work. It simply creates sheetname, sheetname1, sheetname2, ...
I tried setting the mode to "w" but it overwrites any other existing sheet, and I want to keep those.

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Found your question with answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873709/pandas-append-sheet-to-workbook-if-sheet-doesnt-exist-else-overwrite-sheet/56874059

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code as below

```
def save_excel_sheet(df, filepath, sheetname, index=False):
     # Create file if it does not exist
     if not os.path.exists(filepath):
         df.to_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheetname, index=index)

     # Otherwise, add a sheet. Overwrite if there exists one with the same name.
     else:
         with pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay', mode='a') as writer:
             df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=index, startrow=writer.sheets[sheet_name].max_row, header=None)
```

**Pandas version - 2.0.2**